# Sprite Kit works on simulator but not devices

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I am working on a sprite kit based game.  When I run this in the simulator, everything works just fine.  However, when I run this on mu iPod and my iPhone, it shows up blank.  I have put some println's in to track where the problem is.  On the simulator, It show all of them.  On the iOS device, it shows all but GameSceneMain Found.

Thanks for the help.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("View Did Load")
    if let scene = GameSceneMain.unarchiveFromFile("GameSceneMain") as? SKScene {
        // Configure the view.
        println("GameSceneMain Found")
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
    println("Past scene attempt block")
}
```

Comment: the filename is exactly GameSceneMain including case? ios file system is case sensitive

Comment: I checked and don't think that this is the problem.  It loads just fine on the simulator

Comment: simulator filesystem is that of os x, which for most users means case insensitive. Try using nsfilemanager to check if the file exists in the bundle.

Comment: I would check if you still have the GameSceneMain in the main bundle. I bet the archive was saved to your simulator, after which you deleted it. Now every time you run on simulator, the archive is already there unlike the device, which needs to get it from somewhere. I've had this problem before, check if all of the .SKS files are there